# Thunderbird autoconfig doesn't load online xml

Tags: smtp, imap, thunderbird

hopefully someone can help me.

I have written an config xml for thunderbird. While using that in `tb-install-dir/isp/` Filder all is well.
But while uploading to my autoconfig domain, Thunderbird will not load it.

Here's the link: http://autoconfig.lipperts-web.de/config-v1.1.xml

Using it as `tb-install-dir/isp/lipperts-web.de.xml` works very well, but without local copy, TB will irgnore it?

I read here how to configure this service here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autokonfiguration

Comment: So what can you say about TB autoconfig now? Nginx log doesn't even show thath TB tries to access any URL.